# Why do we still not have any moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)

The Temporary Moderator [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) indicates that SE will pick our original temporary moderators roughly a week after the launch of beta.  We are well past that threshold now.  Is there some other criteria that has not yet been reached that is delaying the selection?

Comment: A few days ago Robert mentioned that the [community team is still considering candidates](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/a/213/101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment above:

> A few days ago Robert mentioned that the community team is still considering candidates. – Yannis Rizos 2 hours ago

That's basically it. Candidates are still in the channel and we expect to complete that process shortly.